# Read PDF File using MuPDF with Vudroid

Tags: android, mupdf, vudroid

How can I read different PDF pages in android with Vudroid?

Vudroid only reads only single file at a time and draws the pages, but my requirement is different: I want to read multiple PDF files with first page only.